# Including document counts in the view for each specific count

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a structure such as GROUP and USER. Each group has a number of user members. I need to have a view that returns me a list of groups that also includes the user counts.. How can I do it?

Each GROUP has a set of USERS attached to it. I want the GROUP view to return the number of users that each group has..

the **GROUP** object:

```
 {
    _id : 'Group-A',
    description : 'test group'
 }
```

the **USER** object:

```
{
   _id : 'Bill Murray',
   groupId : 'Group-A',
   email : 'bmurray@gmal.com'
}
```

what I need the **VIEW** to look like

```
{
   groupName : 'Group-A',
   description : 'test group',
   userCount : 45
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a _count reduce:

Map:

```
function(doc){
  if ( doc.groupId ){
     emit(doc.groupId, null);
  }
}
```

Reduce:

```
_count
```

Querying the view with reduce = false would give you:

```
key: "Group-A" value: null
key: "Group-A" value: null
key: "Group-B" value: null
```

Querying with reduce=true you would get:

```
key: null value: 3
```

If you want a count by group, then use reduce=true&group_level=1

```
key: "Group-A" value: 2
key: "Group-B" value: 1
```

Comment: That's great thanks. But is there any way to cram the counts in the original query that returns the full group data?